# Select Statement is not being read but works fine before until the Insert INTO query

Tags: c#, sql-server

Need help for this one my `SELECT` Statement cant be read/execute anymore after I placed the `INSERT INTO` for activity log but works fine before did I do something wrong with my placements?

```
ClayLink.con.Open();

string userid = txt_login.Text;
string password = txt_password.Text;

ClayLink.cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserType FROM Users WHERE Username='" + userid + "'AND Password='" + password + "'", ClayLink.con);
ClayLink.cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALog values ('" + txt_login.Text + "','" + admin.lbl_Username.Text + "','" + admin.label7.Text + "', 'Login Button Click','')", ClayLink.con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ClayLink.adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(ClayLink.cmd);
ClayLink.adapter.Fill(dt);
ClayLink.con.Close(); 

try 
{ 
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
    { 
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "Administrator")
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Logged in as Administrator!");
            admin.Show();
            ClayLink.con.Close();

            ClayLink.con.Open();
            string str = "select * from Users where Username = '" + txt_login.Text + "'";

            ClayLink.cmd = new SqlCommand(str, ClayLink.con);
            ClayLink.dataReader = ClayLink.cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ClayLink.dataReader.Read(); 

            admin.lbl_Username.Text = ClayLink.dataReader["Firstname"].ToString();
            admin.lbl_Usertype.Text = ClayLink.dataReader["UserType"].ToString();

            this.txt_login.Clear();
            this.txt_password.Clear();
            this.Hide();
            ClayLink.con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **NEVER EVER** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Thank you for the alert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these two lines of code:

```
ClayLink.cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserType FROM Users WHERE Username='" + userid + "'AND Password='" + password + "'", ClayLink.con);
ClayLink.cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALog values ('" + txt_login.Text + "','" + admin.lbl_Username.Text + "','" + admin.label7.Text + "', 'Login Button Click','')", ClayLink.con);
```

You are setting `ClayLink.cmd` twice.  The value is the value the second time.

Other notes:

- Use parameters instead of munging query strings with input strings.
- Don't pass unencrypted passwords arounds.
- List the columns you are inserting into when using `insert`.

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped me !